# Remove Ad Malware Safari El Capitan

Tags: macos, safari, malware

I used to have 10.11 yesterday when I saw multiple ads from multiple sites opening when I'm viewing webpages using Safari. I updated to the latest version of the OS, 10.11.6 but it hasn't fixed the issue. I've restarted the OS multiple times. I've tried MalwareBytes as it was suggested in forums. I also tried removing all safari data from Library folders to reset Safari and it still hasn't fixed the issue.
The malware redirects websites I visit to offerland.info / bestphoneapps.mobi / mobrevflwms.com and many other sites.

Solutions would be appreciated.

Comment: [Nuke it from orbit](http://security.stackexchange.com/q/24195/86652)

Answer (score 1):

Other malware removers..

[MacScan 3](http://www.securemac.com/macscan) - [Subscription $50 pa] with free trial. idk whether the free trial will let you actually remove anything it finds. Prime task is to remove bad cookies. I've been using it since v1 & have never 'caught' anything it couldn't kill, though that in itself doesn't prove it will kill everything, only the ones I've seen.

For an actual 'antivirus' - rather than me post a list, it would be better to refer you to [AV-TEST](https://www.av-test.org), which is the closest thing to an actual authority on the subject, or specifically their most recent [Mac report](https://www.av-test.org/en/news/news-single-view/12-security-suites-for-mac-os-x-put-to-the-test/) . As of their last report, July 2016, they list 4 products with a 100% hit-rate, yet only two which can do that without leaning on your machine & slowing it down, BitDefender & ESET. Neither of those are are free.

They update the report twice a year, so the main link should remain usable in future, as the specific July 2016 report falls out of date.

Comment: BitDefender is free on the Mac app store and is exceptionally good at removing adware, IMHO

Comment: I think they have two versions, [paid](http://www.bitdefender.co.uk/solutions/antivirus-for-mac.html) & [free](https://itunes.apple.com/app/bitdefender-virus-scanner/id500154009?mt=12). The av-test was of the paid version.

Comment: Indeed, but for this scenario free is all Milad'd need (just for simple adware detection/removal).